# What noun categorizes jealousy and what verb acts on it?

Tags: word-choice

> Jealousy is the easiest **feeling** to **provoke** ... **invoke** ...

Okay, I'm a bit confused here. Even though the thought is pretty clear, the phrasing seems a bit strained to me. Please tell me the best descriptor of jealousy and what verbs might act on that descriptor.

Answer (score 2):

> Jealousy is the easiest **emotion** to provoke.

Usually one becomes **jealous** because *something happened*, not because one **wants** to become jealous.  If one **wanted** to be jealous it could possible be **invoked** or **called upon**, though jealousy is usually **detrimental** to the person suffering from it.

Jealousy is accompanied by many different **feelings** of insecurity, fear, anger, longing, etc.

Comment: The implication here is that it is easy to make someone else jealous.

Comment: It usually can be, especially if you know which button to push.